# How to iterate through string and concatenate after certain characters

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I am trying to loop through a string and look for a character and join every character after said character.

```
string info = "0 1 2 3 4 5 F->data 95753 info ";

for(int i =0; i < info.length; i++)
  {
    if(info[i] == 'F')
      {
          // join all characters after 'F' Result = "0 1 2 3 4 5 F->data95753info"
       }
```

The Output should be : `0 1 2 3 4 5 F->data95753info`

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're looking to do. Update your question with expected output.

Comment: expected output should be the string "0 1 2 3 4 5 F->data95753info"

Comment: Did you try writing any solution for this? Hint: Use [IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-6.0) method to get the position of `F` in the string.. use [SubString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0) method to get the string after `F` in the string,  use [Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-6.0) method to  a replace space with empty string in the string..

Comment: "join every character" is not specific enough.  You should say "I would like to remove all whitespace characters that occur after the first occurrence of the character to search for".  Then for example, when searching for 'F', your demonstration shows that spaces after the 'F' are removed but spaces before the 'F' are preserved.

Comment: Or maybe just "How can I remove all spaces after the letter 'F'?"

Answer (score 4):

Using Linq you can do something like this

```
String.Join('F',info.Split('F').Select((s,i)=>i==0?s:s. Replace(" ","")))
```

Comment: I was curious about the performance between using Linq or not for something like this. For 10 million iterations, this took 17337ms. The very simple version (with IndexOf and two Substrings) took only 7642ms. I'm a little surprised - interesting solution though.

Comment: @mcky - In other words, it's only half as slow and for a vast majority of situations that's perfectly fine.

Comment: @Enigmativity I don't mean to imply that this is a worse solution because of it. It is the difference of a single microsecond per iteration - absolutely meaningless for any normal application. I was under the impression that Linq was faster, but I guess that's just because of the ease of `AsParallel()`, which would drop the average time down well below the other solution.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looping through the string, use [`String.IndexOf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#overloads) and [`String.Substring()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0) to split your string in half, then use [`String.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_) to remove all of the spaces.
Once you have both halves of the string correct, concatenate them.

Example:

```
string info = "I want to remove the spaces after this: there are no spaces here.";

int index = info.IndexOf(':');
string part1 = info.Substring(0, index);
string part2 = info.Substring(index).Replace(" ", "");
Console.WriteLine (part1 + part2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the easiest way:

```
string info = "0 1 2 3 4 5 F->data 95753 info ";
string output = Regex.Replace(info, @"(?<=F.*)\s", "");
```

That gives me `0 1 2 3 4 5 F->data95753info`.

This is just a look behind regular expression replacement.

Answer (score 0):

```
string info = "0 1 2 3 4 5 F->data 95753 info ";
        int indexofF = info.IndexOf('F');
        string replacement = $"{info.Substring(0,indexofF +1)}{info.Substring(indexofF + 1).Replace(" ",string.Empty)}";
```

- find the index of the character you want to process with
- take string on either side of it using substrings
- replace the spaces on right side